The Empty Set and Vacuous Truths
So I know any statements involving $$\forall x \in \emptyset, P(x).$$ is vacuously true. However, I am a bit confused about statements that involve other bits of information such as $$\exists r < 0, \forall x \in \emptyset, P(x).$$ Is this still vacuously true because of the fact that there is a universal quantifier about elements in the empty set?

The statement $\exists r<0,$ (something that does not mention $r$) is true so long as $\exists r<0$ is true and the something is true.  Whether the whole thing is "vacuously true" presumably depends on your definition of "vacuously true".

@Henry This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information.

@MartinBrandenburg I disagree.  Indeed I would have thought your answer is not an answer as it does not currently explicitly address the "vacuously" part of the question.  My comment asks for a definition.

Let $\top$ be some true statement (it can be a vacuously true statement or not, does not matter). Then $\exists r < 0 \,(\top)$ is a shorthand for $\exists r \, (r < 0 \wedge \top)$. The inner part simplifies to $r < 0$, since $\top$ is true. So, the whole thing is equivalent to $\exists r \,  (r < 0)$. This is not vacuously true, in any case, because we do not quantify over the empty set here.
